# True or false logarithmic branches

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

Say whether the following are true or false. Give a short proof.

1) $log(-z)+i{\pi}$ is a branch of the logarithmic function whose branch cut is the non-negative real axis

2)If $g(z)$ is a branch of the logarithmic function with domain D and $h(z)$ is a branch analytic in D, then there is an integer $m$ with $h(z)=g(z)+2m{\pi}i$

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint for part $a$: if $z=1$, what happens?

Hint for part $b$: if $g$ and $h$ share the same domain, what do you know about the branch cuts in relation to each other? How does this relate to the integer multiples of $2\pi i$?

Comment: I'm not sure about your hints. I think maybe my grasp of a branch cut is shaky.

Comment: If you plug in $1$ into the expression in part $a$, you get $\log(-1)+i\pi$. Is this well-defined?

Comment: For part $b$, what do you know about the geometry of the branch cuts? Are they perpendicular, parallel, askew?

Comment: I believe they are perpendicular

Comment: They're actually the same ray emanating from the origin.

Comment: ok thanks so what does h being analytic mean?